# The auto numbering/bullets of the Source MS Word document do not automatically align with those of the Destination MS Word document

Tags: plugins, ms-word, autonumber

It happens when a user inserts a Word Document(Source) into another Word Document(Destination) - auto numbering/bullets didn't work...

I wont to insert text here, and continue auto-numbering of source as it in destination:
[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr8dc.png)
But it inserting above without auto-numbering:
[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScEAy.png)

I have an answer from MS that it's a feature of MS Word :(.

So, the question is - is it possible to automatically align the above either by use Word Automation ( via C# , .NET Interop Word APIs )?

I mean to align the source document contents as per the destination document’s Auto-numbering. The same is about Bullets...
Please help - we are open to any suggestions/ recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Both documents need to have the same style definitions for both the **Paragraph Style** of the text being copied and also the **List Style** that organizes the numbering or bullets. Using automation, you can copy styles between the files before actually moving the numbered or bulleted text.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with John.

The basic idea is to use the Define New MultiLevel List Dialog to define a new multilevel list in which each level you would be using is attached to an existing paragraph style. A paragraph style can be attached to only one level in one list. Then use the styles to apply the numbering.
Once you have them set up, you apply the numbering by using the styles, not the numbering controls.

Setting up the numbering linked to styles can seem a bit convoluted. Step-by-step instructions for doing it in Windows can be found here:

- http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html
- Backup: http://web.archive.org/web/20130510174814/http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html
- For a Mac, John has a page showing the Mac controls to accomplish it.
- http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/06/outline-numbering-in-word-for-os-x/
- Backup link: http://web.archive.org/web/20200912134758/http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/06/outline-numbering-in-word-for-os-x/

These describe the only known ways to have consistent numbering in Word in heavily-edited / co-authored documents.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon - You should quote and cite the relevant information from your external links.

Comment: I amended the post to give more about the procedures. 
I also added web archive copies of the links. People do need this information in detail. I do not have permission to copy the pages. If you feel that this is not sufficient after reviewing those pages, feel free to delete my post. I am still learning.

Comment: I would rather you edit your answer, so the relevant information is contained within the answer, instead of an external page.

Comment: @Security Hound -- I amended this one as much as I am willing to do. I will delete it if it does not meet community standards. The two pages I link give detail and I am not comfortable copying that detail here without permission. One of those belongs to the other person who answered and he did not provide excerpts from his page here. Nor did he link to it, I realize. What you are saying may well be the reason he did not link to it even though it would help the questioner. -- I hoped that by providing the archival links it was my hope that I was addressing the ephemeral nature of links.

Comment: @Security Hound -- The following language has the relevant information: The basic idea is to use the Define New MultiLevel List Dialog to define a new multilevel list in which each level you would be using is attached to an existing paragraph style. A paragraph style can be attached to only one level in one list. Then use the styles to apply the numbering. Once you have them set up, you apply the numbering by using the styles, not the numbering controls. The linked pages are useful it taking someone step-by-step through doing that. -- I will delete this myself unless meets community standards.